# ERROR 404: ajax can't connect to the @requestmapping

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

My ajax cannot connect to here and when i see F12->Network->Headers  i saw requestUrl has double "/web": http://localhost:8080/create_user_web_war_exploded/web/web/done
But my delete page just has 1 "/web" at link @RequestMapping(value = "/web/delete",method = RequestMethod.GET). I think that make error 404 at my web, because all others page has link is "/'project_name'/'Request value'"

```
//My controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/web/done")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @DeleteMapping
    public String delete( @RequestBody UserDTO model,@PathVariable("id") long id){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("web/done");
        userService.deleteUser(model.getId());
        return "done";
    }

}
```

```
//My ajax
function deleteUser(data) {
    console.log("hihi");
    console.log("done");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',

        url: 'web/done',
        data: data,
        /*dataType:'json',*/
        /*contentType:'application/json',*/
        success: function () {
            console.log("done");
        },


    }).done(function (response) {
        alert("Job done!!!!");
    }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    });
```

Comment: What error you are getting ? Add the error log

Comment: Status Code: 404

Comment: and this is Request URL: http://localhost:8080/create_user_web_war_exploded/web/web/done

Comment: May be you are already in `..../web` url

Comment: it has 2 "/web", i dont know why because others page dont has it, just "/web" one time

Comment: I am in ..../web/delete and  i type id i want to delete and click button, it will go to ..../web/done, not ..../web/web/done, i dont know why

Comment: Have you tried to remote the "web" workd from your AJAX call? like in the part: url: 'web/done', just put  url: '/done' and check what happens there.

Comment: yes i did, it become ..../web/done but error 400

Comment: Your URL should start with a `/` and next to that your mapping is wrong as there is no `@PathVariable` defined so it wll never map. Either the URL needs to be `/web/done/{id}` or the `@PathVariable` doesn't belong there at all.

Comment: it's not work :(, i was suggested by IDE so i press enter it, but i added "/", it still not work, i remove @Path... but not work

Comment: i added "/" to ajax url, i fix problem "/web" twicetimes, but i dont start with "/" at my function to create new user, it still working for create

Comment: Open Postman, create a @GetMapping in your controller and make sure you can reach the getrequest so that you know what is the correct url. Since you are getting 404, url doesnt find anything - means url is wrong

Answer (score 0):

The principal map from the controller is "/web/done" but on the main method, you are calling only "web/done" without the first /. Try adding the / on Ajax

Comment: still not working, in other page i still use like it and it work (it is the suggest of IDEA so i just need to press enter, i think it not the problem but it fix the problem double "/web" - I dont know why), here it s not work, still error 404